# Get-AutomationPSCredential in InlineScript with Verbose

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

Can anybody explain to me why verbose message '3' is not being displayed? If I don't assign Get-AutomationPSCredential to variable $Credential2 then the '3' is being displayed.

```psh
workflow a 
{
  $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
  Write-Verbose -Message '0'

  $Credential1 = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name CRE-AUTO-WindowsLocalAdmin 
  Write-Verbose -Message '1'

  inlinescript
  {
    Write-Verbose -Message '2'
    $Credential2 = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name CRE-AUTO-WindowsLocalAdmin
    $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
    Write-Verbose -Message '3'
  } 
  Write-Verbose -Message '4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Felix, I just tested your example in a PowerShell Workflow Runbook and it successfully ran, and produced all off your messages, 0-4. There should be no reason that 3 is not written as verbose output. Are there any special circumstances you are using, i.e Hybrid Runbook Worker? Below is a snip of running your script on my automation account. Let me know.[image]

Comment: George, Thanks for helping out. Sorry, forgot to mention that I only have this issue when executing locally on my PC in ISE using the Azure Automation ISE add-on. Actually seen the same behavior on colleagues PCs.